# How to get background image from UITableViewStyleGrouped for any UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I would like to have a UIView with the same background as a UITableView with the UITableViewStyleGrouped style (its that grey-white pattern seen in the Settings App, for example). Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

MrMage

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
```